# What does の何? mean when used like this?

Tags: questions

> 素になった途端に一回もニコリもしないの何?

The character revealed his true personality, and one of the other character commented this.

My reading is "After becoming honest/exposing your true personality, you didn't smile once" I suppose in contrast to before where he smiles a lot.

But what function does の何 here adds?

Comment: When translated into English, this "何?" is not simple "What" but rather "What's up with" or "What's going on with". This is a rather blunt use of 何. A safer way of saying this is "の(は)どういうこと?"

Answer (score 5):

> [素になった途端に一回もニコリもしないの(は)][何]?

That の is colloquial for のは and is separate from the 何. The speaker is asking 何 about the nominalized phrase. So the translation would be "What's the deal with you not smiling one bit after showing your true self?"